# Populating a second dropdown box based on the selection of another using webservice to get information

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, drop-down-menu

I have populated a drop-down using a web-service called KeywordService which hits the .NET controller, populating a list from another project.

Following is the angular controller, The web developer here said that I needed to monitor the keyword change event, Pass the keyword to the getQualifier function. How to "monitor" it? can anyone let me know how to do this?

```
var StockItemMultiMillInquiryController = function ($scope, $sce, $rootScope, $modal, $window, StockItemMultiMillService, KeywordService, QualifierService) {


$rootScope.title = 'Stock Item Multi Mill Inquiry';
$scope.allMills = [];
$scope.mill = '';
$scope.stockNumber = '';
$scope.description = '';
$scope.qtyonhand = '';
$scope.qualifier = '';
$scope.costType = '';
$scope.keyword = '';
$scope.allKeywords = [];
$scope.qualifier = keyword;
$scope.selectedQualifier = '';
$scope.allQualifiers = [];


KeywordService.getKeyword().then(function (keywords) {
    $scope.allKeywords = keywords
});

QualifierService.getQualifier().then(function (qualifier) {
    $scope.allQualifiers = qualifier
});
```

and this is the **service**:

```
 // Keyword service for dropdown ticket #54507
app.service('KeywordService', function ($http, cache) {
   return {
    getKeyword: function () {
        var keywords = cache.get('keyword');
        if (!keywords) {
            return $http({ method: 'JSONP', url: "/api/core/keyword/keyword?callback=JSON_CALLBACK", params: {} }).then(function (result) {
                if (result.data.success) {
                    cache.put('keyword', result.data.data);
                    return result.data.data;
                } else {
                    return [];
                }
            });
        } else {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(keywords);
            return deferred.promise;
          }
       }
    };
});



  // Qualifier service for dropdown ticket #54507
 app.service('QualifierService', function ($http, cache) {
    return {
      getQualifier: function () {
        var qualifiers = cache.get('qualifier');
        if (!qualifiers) {
            return $http({ method: 'JSONP', url: "/api/core/qualfier/qualifier?callback=JSON_CALLBACK", params: {qualifier: qualifier} }).then(function (result) {
                if (result.data.success) {
                    cache.put('qualifier', result.data.data);
                    return result.data.data;
                } else {
                    return [];
                }
            });
        } else {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(qualifiers);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
       }
    };
 });
```

the **.NET controller that the service calls for keyword and qualifier**

```
 Imports PCA.Core.Search
 Imports PCA.Core.Web.JSON

 Public Class KeywordController
   Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

' GET: /Plants
<PCA.Core.Web.CompressionFilter> _
Function Keyword(callback As String) As ActionResult
    Dim res As New PCA.Core.Web.JSON.Response

    Dim keywordList As New List(Of ViewModels.Core.Keyword)
    For Each u As Trident.Core.Core.Keyword In Trident.Core.Globals.TridentApp.ApplicationCache.Keywords.Keywords
        keywordList.Add(New ViewModels.Core.Keyword(u))
    Next
    Try
        res.success = True
        res.message = ""
        res.data = keywordList.OrderBy(Function(c) c.description)
        Return New PCA.Core.Web.JSON.JSONPResult() With { _
             .Data = res,
             .Callback = callback
            }
    Catch ex As Exception
        res.success = False
        res.message = ex.Message
        res.data = ""
        Return New PCA.Core.Web.JSON.JSONPResult() With { _
             .Data = res,
             .Callback = callback
            }
    End Try
  End Function
 End Class

Imports PCA.Core.Search
Imports PCA.Core.Web.JSON

 Public Class QualifierController
     Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

' GET: /Plants
<PCA.Core.Web.CompressionFilter> _
Function Qualifier(callback As String, keyword As String) As ActionResult
    Dim res As New PCA.Core.Web.JSON.Response

    Dim qualifierList As New List(Of ViewModels.Core.Qualifier)
    For Each u As Trident.Core.Core.Qualifier In Trident.Core.Globals.TridentApp.ApplicationCache.Keywords.Qualifiers(keyword)
        qualifierList.Add(New ViewModels.Core.Qualifier(u))
    Next
    Try
        res.success = True
        res.message = ""
        res.data = qualifierList.OrderBy(Function(c) c.description)
        Return New PCA.Core.Web.JSON.JSONPResult() With { _
             .Data = res,
             .Callback = callback
            }
    Catch ex As Exception
        res.success = False
        res.message = ex.Message
        res.data = ""
        Return New PCA.Core.Web.JSON.JSONPResult() With { _
             .Data = res,
             .Callback = callback
            }
    End Try
   End Function
```

This is the **ViewModel for Keyword and Qualifier**:

```
Namespace ViewModels.Core

Public Class Keyword

    Private m_keyword As String
    Private _m_keywords As List(Of Core.Keyword)

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(keyword As Trident.Core.Core.Keyword)

        m_keyword = keyword.Description.ToString

    End Sub

    Sub New(m_keywords As List(Of Core.Keyword))
        ' TODO: Complete member initialization 
        _m_keywords = m_keywords
    End Sub

    Public Property description As String
        Get
            Return m_keyword
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_keyword = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

End Namespace
```

**Qualifier:**

```
Namespace ViewModels.Core

Public Class Qualifier

    Private m_qualifier As String
    Private _m_qualifiers As List(Of Core.Qualifier)

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(qualifier As Trident.Core.Core.Qualifier)

        m_qualifier = qualifier.Description.ToString

    End Sub

    Sub New(m_keywords As List(Of Core.Qualifier))
        ' TODO: Complete member initialization 
        m_qualifier = m_qualifier
    End Sub

    Public Property description As String
        Get
            Return m_qualifier
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_qualifier = value
        End Set
    End Property

   End Class

  End Namespace
```

and this is the **html file that i have the drop downs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <!--  View for the Stock item multi mill inquiry Ticket #54507-->
 <html>
 <head>
     <title>Stock Item Multi Mill Inquiry</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">


            <div class="form-group">

                <select class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" style="width: 92%" ng-model="mill">
                    <option value="">Select a Mill </option>
                    <option value="608">Tomahawk Mill</option>
                    <option value="610">Valdosta Mill</option>
                    <option value="620">Counce Mill</option>
                    <option value="622">Filer Mill</option>
                    <option value="650">DeRidder Mill</option>
                    <option value="651">Wallula Mill</option>
                    <option value="652">Jackson Mill</option>
                    <option value="653">International Falls Mill</option>
                </select>&nbsp;<br/><br/>

                <select class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" style="width: 92%" ng-model="keyword">
                    <option value="">Select a Keyword</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="keyword in allKeywords" value="{{keyword.description}}"> {{keyword.description}} </option>
                </select><br/><br/>

                <select  class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" style="width: 92%" ng-model="selectedQualifier">
                    <option value="">Select a Qualifier</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="qualifier in allQualifiers" value="{{qualifier.description}}"> {{qualifier.description}} </option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Comment: The code you posted is a lot... or better, a lot more than needed. Anyway to monitor the "keyword change" event just use `ng-change` attribute on `<select>` element to invoke a function that call the server side API and populate another `<select>` element. Basically you need something like this `<select ng-change='populateSecondSelectFunction()'>`

Comment: @edgar post a shorter code buddy, where you feel the issue is occurring, users will not read your entire stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-change`, it triggers when the value of the select box changes.

```
ng-change="getQualifier(keyword)"
```

Pass the model of the first select to the second on Something like:

```
            <select class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" style="width: 92%" ng-model="keyword">
                <option value="">Select a Keyword</option>
                <option ng-repeat="keyword in allKeywords" value="{{keyword.description}}"> {{keyword.description}} </option>
            </select><br/><br/>

            <select  class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" style="width: 92%" ng-model="selectedQualifier" ng-change="getQualifier(keyword)">
                <option value="">Select a Qualifier</option>
                <option ng-repeat="qualifier in allQualifiers" value="{{qualifier.description}}"> {{qualifier.description}} </option>
            </select>
```

Hope that's what you wish to achieve!

Comment: when i declare my QualifierService at the top of the angular controller it causes my dropdown for keyword not to populate? ive narrowed it down to that. ive commented everything related to qualifier out and ive commented and not commented that declaration and the dropdown data appears and disappears